# When client shutdown by pressing Ctrl+c the server continuously process previous input. Why?

Tags: c, sockets

I have a client server program in C. Client send the command while server receives it.

But if client shutdown by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  the server application process the previous input.

### Example.

```
CLient.c                                Server.c
-------------------------------------------------
Enter COmmand: adf                     Command from client: adf

Enter COmmand: bbb                     Command from client: bbb

Enter Command: Ctrl+c                  Command from client: bb
```

---

I don't understand why it process the previous input.

Given below is my main logic.

```
main(){

    // bind, listen, accept is done.

            while(!done && !shutFlag){      //  Main server command Loop
        done = ReceiveRequestMessage(&request, connectedSock );
        if(done)
        {
            printf("Client closed the connection while recv() \n");
            printf("Listening for new client connection to establish... \n");
            connectedSock = accept(srvSock, (struct sockaddr *)&connectSAddr, &addrLen );
            printf("GetLastError: %d\n", GetLastError());
            done = FALSE;
            continue;

        }

        request.record[strlen(request.record)] ='\0';
        commandLen = strcspn(request.record, "\n\t");
        memcpy(sysCommand, request.record, commandLen);
        sysCommand[commandLen] = '\0';

        printf("Request recieved from client: %s -> Hex: %X\n\n", request.record, *(request.record));
    }

}
```

`ReceiveRequestMessage` Function:

```
static BOOL ReceiveRequestMessage(REQUEST *pRequest, SOCKET sd){
    LONG32 nRemainRecv = 0, nRecv;
    LPBYTE pBuffer;
    BOOL disconnect = FALSE;

    nRemainRecv = RQ_HEADER_LEN;
    pBuffer = (LPBYTE) pRequest;
    while(nRemainRecv > 0 &&  !disconnect )
    {
        nRecv = recv (sd, pBuffer, nRemainRecv, 0); // Reading the 1st 4 bytes(length of record)to pRequest.
        if ( nRecv > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received in request.rqLen: %d\n", nRecv);
        else if ( nRecv == SOCKET_ERROR ){
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            return TRUE;
        }

        disconnect = (nRecv == 0);      // check connection is closed 
        nRemainRecv -= nRecv;
        pBuffer += nRecv;       
    }

    /*  Read the request record */
    nRemainRecv = pRequest->rqLen;
    /* Exclude buffer overflow */
    nRemainRecv = min(nRemainRecv, MAX_RQRS_LEN);

    pBuffer = (LPSTR)pRequest->record;  
    while(nRemainRecv > 0 && !disconnect)
    {
        nRecv = recv(sd, pBuffer, nRemainRecv, 0);
        if(nRecv > 0)
            printf("Bytes Received in request.record: %d\n", nRecv);
        else if(nRecv == SOCKET_ERROR){
            printf("Connection closed");
            return TRUE;
        }

        disconnect = (nRecv == 0);          // check connection is closed 
        nRemainRecv -= nRecv;
        pBuffer += nRecv;       
    }

    return disconnect;
}
```

How can I eliminate the last print statement after clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in client?

Means:

Whenever Client disconnects by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or in any way. How can I notify Server?

Comment: you will have more control over what happens if you catch the Ctrl+C signal in a custom handler.

Comment: `request.record[strlen(request.record)] ='\0';` doesn't make sense... it places a null character at the location of the first existing null character.

Comment: Can you post server log, so we can see messages produced by your code. Error can be either in client code (it send packet on termination) or in server code (it incorrectly detect client termination and print previous packet).

Comment: `request.record[strlen(request.record)] ='\0';` more over it is possible to send request without '\0' and get server segfault.

Comment: "*Connection closed*" should read "*recv() failed*". "*Connection closed [by peer]*" should be logged if `0` bytes had been "received".

Answer (score 1):

- Function `ReceiveRequestMessage()` returns the value of its variable `disconnect`.
- That variable is set nonzero only if `recv()` returns `0`.
- The documentation for `recv()` promises a return value of `0` only for the case that the remote end performs an orderly shutdown (and no more data are available to receive).  It will definitely return `-1`, not `0`, if an error occurs.
- It is not safe to assume that the client will perform an orderly shutdown every time it effectively disconnects, and in particular, it is not safe to assume that it will perform one when it is killed by a signal, as happens when you send it a Ctrl+c.
- If `ReceiveRequestMessage()` returns `0` without modifying the object pointed to by its `pRequest` parameter, then it will appear to the caller that the previously-sent request was repeated.  This is what you are observing.